# Access Jenkins remotely through apache

Tags: apache, url, jenkins, configure, accessible

I am just trying to set up my Jenkins URL so that I can access it from another machine.  I don't really know what I'm doing.  I tried following several tutorials and haven't gotten it to work yet.  Here is what I have in my Jenkins.conf file located at /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy *>
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPreseveHost on
  ProxyPass /http://24.117.132.56:8080/ nocanon
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
</VirtualHost>
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You missed the space

```
ProxyPass /http://24.117.132.56:8080/  # <-- wrong
ProxyPass / http://24.117.132.56:8080/ # <-- correct
```

Also you missed character here:

```
ProxyPreseveHost on  # <-- wrong
ProxyPreserveHost on # <-- correct
```